# Soapui assertion for part of URL in XML response

Tags: xml, parsing, groovy, soapui

I have XML response that contains many info and one of them is something like MyURL and contains URL which should contain at the end `myid`.
How can I create assertion in Soapui to check if URL contains `myid` if it looks something like this:

```
<stream audio="eng">         <myURL>http://xxxxxx.test.com/test26/test32456749&myid=12345678910</myURL>
</stream>
```

ID is changing after refresh only lenght should be still the same.

Comment: Have you edited the url? there is supposed to be a `?` which is missing.

Comment: vb381, have you got chance to try the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

Use Script Assertion for the same test step where you are getting that response.  Follow in-line comments.

```
//Check if the response is not empty
assert context.response, 'Response is null or empty'

//Chang the name of the element to find if required
def elementToFind = 'myURL'

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)
def node = xml.'**'.find{it.name() == elementToFind }

//Check if there is such element
assert elementToFind == node?.name(), "$elementToFind does not exists in the response"

//Get the parameters from the url
def params = node.text().toURL().query?.split('&')

//Convert it map / properties
def props = params.collectEntries { param -> param.split('=').collect { URLDecoder.decode(it) }}

log.info props.myid
```

Comment: it is not working for me :/ I don't know scripting, I tried to update it for my xml, just changed some elements names but this assertion only failed, I can't see nothing in log...

Comment: sry, it is working great now :) Just how can I check also lenght of this id? If it should be e.g. 16 characters

Comment: How about `props.myid.size()`? By the appreciate if you can up vote & [accept it as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. And another one thing. Some of urls are starting with rtsp and I want to check if there is not this myid. But with any of rtsp response I got error unknown protocol: rtsp error...